# Is the fine structure constant a function of electron mass?

Tags: electrons, mass, quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants

The main statement is: the EM coupling constant is energy dependent, and the fine structure constant (FSS) is the low energy limit. This means that the flow of the coupling constant vanishes when the energy does not suffice any more to create the lightest charged particles, electrons and positrons (there only remain the classical tree diagrams). Below the electron rest mass energy virtual electrons and positrons are frozen out.
Consequently, the FTS is a function of the electron mass, and if the electron mass comes from the Higgs coupling, of the Higgs coupling.
All QFT literature is about the scaling limit and high energy (where the electron is effectively massless), and and no clear statements about low energy can be found anywhere. But in statistical mechanics terms the above statement appears to be the only reasonable.

Comment: If anything you can relate the fine structure constant to the electron charge by setting c=epsilon0=hbar=1. Isn't that the most common choice of units here? Then alpha=e^2/4pi I believe.

Comment: Remember that the fine structure constant was *discovered* in atomic physics, at "low" energy, long before QFT. That's how it got its name, from (mainly optical) spectroscopy.

Comment: I recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant There are many physical interpretations, some depending on the ratio things that contain $m_e$ (but it cancels). There is also a discussion of its running with energy scale, esp in the context of electroweak theory. It's too involved to repost as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I know you worked hard on this and want a more useful answer, so sorry to be negative: the definition of the fine structure constant, as a constant, is just the low energy limit. It will not change with energy---the coupling that it is the low energy limit of, can scale. Indeed, for all the renormalised quantities, mass, charge, etc, the low energy limits are defined not to change.

> This means that the flow of the coupling constant vanishes when the energy does not suffice any more to create the lightest charged particles, electrons and positrons (there only remain the classical tree diagrams).

No, it does not vanish, literally by definition, and also because the low energy limit is the classical limit that we abundantly see in experiments.

> Below the electron rest mass energy virtual electrons and positrons are frozen out.

No, the QFT corrections making up Lamb shift is mostly the superbly low energy ones, not even the low energy ones.

> All QFT literature is about the scaling limit and high energy (where the electron is effectively massless), and and no clear statements about low energy can be found anywhere.

This is simply not true. Infrared divergence has a lot of literature too. In fact, it is one of the biggest problem in QFT, with a million dollar Millennium Prize for proving things about it.

---

Actually, QFT is already so mature that there is no more need for the particular thing you are looking at. It is possible to start with purely renormalised quantities and not have any mention of bare quantities, and no infinities and their renormalisation away thereof. Just purely getting the perturbation series alone and nothing else. In particular, no UV divergence, no problems at high energy limit.

Comment: So QFT can predict the fine structure constant from first principles?

Comment: Now, the FSC is the low energy limit 1/137 of the running coupling constant. There therefore is a characteristic scale where the (logarithmic) flow comes to an end. The question is about whether this scale is the electron mass. If so, then the FSC is a function of the electron mass (high energy physics remains the same). If virtual electrons and positrons are frozen out below the electron mass, then there still remain residual effects (Lamb shift).

Comment: You are getting it backwards. You must keep the low energy physics the same, not the high energy physics (which, as mentioned, it is already solved, so high energy physics is also known). There is no scale at which it vanishes, i.e. there is never any freezing out of the virtual particles, high energy or low energy.

Comment: Still not convinced. Why must I keep the low energy physics the same? Just suppose the electron mass (generated by  Higgs coupling) were different. If it where smaller, then the coupling constant would flow to a smaller value.

Comment: The low energy physics is where classical electrodynamics works. Any new complicated physical theory must agree with older theories where older theories worked properly!

Comment: To repeat once again. A) At high energies the electron mass is negligible and the coupling constant flows. B) At low energies the flow stops and the coupling constant reaches the value 1/137. C) The characteristic scale, where the flow stops is the electron mass (there is no other scale in simple quantum electrodynamics). D) Consequently the value 1/137 is determined by the electron mass. --- This is not a new theory, just a question of interpretation. If the electron mass were different, we would not have 1/137. It is more natural the keep the UV fixed (the atoms in statistical physics).

Comment: Not only are you insisting upon a weird "interpretation" that has been shown to disagree with the standard literature in many places, but you also want to decouple a critical component of a physical theory with the actual real world physical manifestation that it needs to connect with in order to even have a sensible interpretation. You are free to work with such flights of fantasy on your own, but PSE is not the correct place to discuss about them. Tell us after you have convinced the physics community that your scheme works. Just works, not even working better, just works.